# How to webscrape share counts in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, webharvest

I am trying to download the share count from the left SumoMe plugin of this website http://www.r-bloggers.com/erum-2016-first-european-conference-for-the-programming-language-r/

I try to use R code based on `rvest` package

```
> library(rvest)
Loading required package: xml2
> url <- 'http://www.r-bloggers.com/erum-2016-first-european-conference-for-the-programming-language-r/'
> read_html(url) %>%
+   html_nodes('.wpusb-counts span')
{xml_nodeset (1)}
[1] <span data-element="total-share"></span>
```

But have received empty response.
The page looks like to start with 0 share-count and then it updates after a few second after you spend time on that website. Can someone could suggest any possible solution to that or advice any package? Is RSelenium a good package for that? I haven't used it before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that value is loaded asynchronously by javascript so yes, [RSelenium](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/) may be your best bet. I ended up using the xpath selector in Firebug to pass that parameter to `browser$findElement`

```
library(RSelenium)

browser <- remoteDriver()
browser$open()
browser$navigate('http://www.r-bloggers.com/erum-2016-first-european-conference-for-the-programming-language-r/')
value <- browser$findElement(using = 'xpath', '/html/body/div[5]/div/div[1]/div/span')
print(value$getElementText())

[[1]]
[1] "7"
```

Comment: Simple, short and amazing. R is powerful! Did You Have to use startServer function for that snippet?

Comment: I did not, but am also running ubuntu 14.04 and it worked without that command but may be a different story on another OS.

Comment: I get `> library(RSelenium)
Loading required package: RCurl
Loading required package: bitops
Loading required package: RJSONIO
Loading required package: XML

Attaching package: ‘XML’

The following object is masked from ‘package:rvest’:

    xml

> 
> browser <- remoteDriver()
> browser$open()
[1] "Connecting to remote server"
Undefined error in RCurl call.
Error in queryRD(paste0(serverURL, "/session"), "POST", qdata = toJSON(serverOpts)) :`